# Restrict user access using session - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, master-pages

I am new to programming. I have developed a web application, on login page I am capturing the session id if the login is successful and redirect the user to the home page.

My query - Is it possible to restrict users from accessing web pages based on their role by using the session control in the master page. If so, how to hide certain web pages?

Login page code -

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from LoginDB where (EmpCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = @EmpCode) and (Password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS =@Password)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpCode", txtLogin.Text.Trim());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPwd.Text.Trim());
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var userRow = dt.Rows[0];
    Session["idname"] = userRow["Name"].ToString();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + "Login Success!" + "')</script>");
    Session["identity"] = txtLogin.Text;
    Response.Redirect("Mainpage.aspx", false);
}
else
{
    txtLogin.Text = "";
    ShowMessage("UserId / Password is Not Correct!");
}
con.Close();
```

Code to be used in master page,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string mnm = Session["identity"].ToString();
   if (mnm == "NormalUser")
   {
       //Hide certain web pages like Asset.aspx web page
   }       
}
```

Comment: Oh... I wish I could get you by your hand and guide you on your path... There's so much to be said...

Comment: @AndreCalil sorry for the trouble, can you please tell the right way to do it.

Comment: no trouble at all, my friend. It's just that, there's so much I'd like to talk here that it would go beyond this interaction. It's webforms, you're storing the password as plain text, you're using the session, you're trying to do access control through texts... I'd like to help you understand these points, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you that check roles of user in [`Page.OnInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.oninit) for each aspx you have instead of doing that in  master page. For example in `Asset.aspx.cs` you can do that as follows:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    string mnm = Session["identity"].ToString();
    if (mnm != "NormalUser")//check whatever you want with the identity
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("You are not allowed to view this page");
    }  
}
```

So that you can apply this approach for other pages.

Comment: Page load event is fired after `OnInit` is completed . So there is no need to check user permission in Page_load again. See: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140))

Comment: i tried this, but having error when executing, "throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("You are not allowed to view this page");" line.

Comment: @santosh Sorry but it is hard to understand from that. Could you give some detail where do you get exception etc..?

Comment: i overcame that error by redirecting the user to home page when they tried to access the restricted page. Is it ok?

Comment: Sure, for example you can `Response.Redirect("~/AccessDenied.aspx");` instead of throwing an exception. It is totally up to you..